# Why autoboxing does not occur in this context?

Tags: java, arrays, list, autoboxing

I would like to know why autoboxing does not occur in the following:

```
int [] array = new int[]{1,3,6,2,-1,6};// if it had been Integer instead of int, would have worked.
List<Integer> liston = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Is there any particular reason why it does not autobox automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can read on Autoboxing [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html):

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes
>   between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper
>   classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a
>   Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is
>   called unboxing.

and as you can read at the end, the types tat are auto boxed are: boolean, byte, char, float, int, long and short. **array are not autoboxed**

it might seems very logical for you that the compiler will do that, but that kind of behavior is very complicated and required a very sophisticated compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Why would autoboxing be needed here?

- argument of `Array.asList` is varargs `T...` which can be interpreted as `T[]`
- generics require Object type,

If you pass `Integer[]` then `T` in `T[]` will be understood as `Integer` so Array.asList will return `List<Integer>`.
But if you pass array (and all arrays are also Object type) then `T` can (and will) be `int[]` making result of Array.asList `List<int[]>`.

Demo.

```
int[] array = new int[]{1,3,6,2,-1,6};
//                        |
//                        +-----------------------+
List<int[]> liston = Arrays.asList(array);//      |
System.out.println(liston.get(0)[1]);//will print 3
```